# Comparing two different processes based on the real, user and sys times

Tags: python, linux, node.js, time

I have been through other answers on SO about real,user and sys times. In this question, apart from the theory, I am interested in understanding the practical implications of the times being reported by two different processes, achieving the same task.

I have a python program and a nodejs program https://github.com/rnanwani/vips_performance. Both work on a set of input images and process them to obtain different outputs. Both using libvips implementations.
Here are the times for the two

**Python**

**real**    1m17.253s
**user**    1m54.766s
**sys** 0m2.988s

**NodeJS**

**real**    1m3.616s
**user**    3m25.097s
**sys** 0m8.494s

The real time (the wall clock time as per other answers is lesser for NodeJS, which as per my understanding means that the entire process from input to output, finishes much quicker on NodeJS. But the user and sys times are very high as compared to Python. Also using the htop utility, I see that NodeJS process has a CPU usage of about 360% during the entire process maxing out the 4 cores. Python on the other hand has a CPU usage from 250% to 120% during the entire process.

I want to understand a couple of things

1. Does a smaller real time and a higher user+sys time mean that the process (in this case Node) utilizes the CPU more efficiently to complete the task sooner?
2. What is the practical implication of these times - which is faster/better/would scale well as the number of requests increase?

Comment: There's no real way to provide answers to these questions by only looking at the times.  Whether something is better depends on your preferences, and how it scales depends on the actual workload.

Comment: In the node.js version, you're totally dependent upon the `sharp` module performance.  I'd say you haven't figured out whether you're testing the sharp implementation on node.js or whether you're testing node.js.  To make this a meaningful test of the node.js vs. python environments, you need the same implementation of your image modifications in both.  Otherwise, you're just testing a python library vs. a node.js library to see which library is better in its environment and it doesn't really tell you anything about the strength/weakness of the environment itself.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But in general, lets say I change my test to a valid one. In such a scenario, does a high CPU usage (high user+sys time with low real time) means better CPU utilization?

Comment: Your python code runs on a single thread while the asynchronous fs.readdir() runs on multiple threads in your Node.js code. While an actual answer to your question varies based on your preferences etc. as @NickBastin suggested IMO I would expect to see a greater real time improvement from the Node.js code to claim that it is as "efficient" as the python code. In roughly the same amount of real time the Node.js code has run nearly three times as many instructions on the CPU. Test the time complexity of these programs by taking samples of time with larger inputs.

Comment: I tried doing the same. For lesser number of images/operations per image, python outperforms node. As I increase the number, node starts outperforming python, and the gap in real time increases. At the same time user time of node increases manifold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that node is running more than one vips pipeline at once, whereas python is strictly running one after the other. Pipeline startup and shutdown is mostly single-threaded, so if node starts several pipelines at once, it can probably save some time, as you observed.

You load your JPEG images in random access mode, so the whole image will be decompressed to memory with libjpeg. This is a single-threaded library, so you will never see more than 100% CPU use there.

Next, you do resize/rotate/crop/jpegsave. Running through these operations, resize will thread well, with the CPU load increasing as the square of the reduction, the rotate is too simple to have much effect on runtime, and the crop is instant. Although the jpegsave is single-threaded (of course) vips runs this in a separate background thread from a write-behind buffer, so you effectively get it for free.

I tried your program on my desktop PC (six hyperthreaded cores, so 12 hardware threads). I see:

```
$ time ./rahul.py indir outdir
clearing output directory - outdir
real    0m2.907s
user    0m9.744s
sys 0m0.784s
```

That looks like we're seeing 9.7 / 2.9, or about a 3.4x speedup from threading, but that's very misleading. If I set the vips threadpool size to 1, you see something closer to the true single-threaded performance (though it still uses the jpegsave write-behind thread):

```
$ export VIPS_CONCURRENCY=1
$ time ./rahul.py indir outdir
clearing output directory - outdir
real    0m18.160s
user    0m18.364s
sys 0m0.204s
```

So we're really getting 18.1 / 2.97, or a 6.1x speedup.

Benchmarking is difficult and real/user/sys can be hard to interpret. You need to consider a lot of factors:

- Number of cores and number of hardware threads
- CPU features like SpeedStep and TurboBoost, which will clock cores up and down depending on thermal load
- Which parts of the program are single-threaded
- IO load
- Kernel scheduler settings

And I'm sure many others I've forgotten.

If you're curious, libvips has it's own profiler which can help give more insight into the runtime behaviour. It can show you graphs of the various worker threads, how long they are spending in synchronisation, how long in housekeeping, how long actually processing your pixels, when memory is allocated, and when it finally gets freed again. There's a blog post about it here:

http://libvips.blogspot.co.uk/2013/11/profiling-libvips.html

Answer (score 1):

**Does a smaller real time and a higher user+sys time mean that the process (in this case Node) utilizes the CPU more efficiently to complete the task sooner?**

It doesn't necessarily mean they utilise the processor(s) more efficiently.

- The higher **user** time means that Node is utilising more user space processor time, and in turn complete the task quicker. As stated by Luke Exton, the cpu is spending more time on "Code you wrote/might look at"
- The higher **sys** time means there is more context switching happening, which makes sense from your htop utilisation numbers. This means the scheduler (kernel process) is jumping between Operating system actions, and user space actions. This is the time spent finding a CPU to schedule the task onto.

**What is the practical implication of these times - which is faster/better/would scale well as the number of requests increase?**

The question of implementation is a long one, and has many caveats. I would assume from the python vs Node numbers that the Python threads are longer, and in turn doing more processing inline. Another thing to note is the GIL in python. Essentially python is a single threaded application, and you can't easily break out of this. This could be a contributing factor to the Node implementation being quicker (using real threads). 
The Node appears to be written to be correctly threaded and to split many tasks out. The advantages of the highly threaded application will have a tipping point where you will spend MORE time trying to find a free cpu for a new thread, than actually doing the work. When this happens your python implementation might start being faster again.

Answer (score 1):

The higher user+sys time means that the process had more running threads and as you've noticed by looking at 360% used almost all available CPU resources of your 4-cores. That means that NodeJS process is already limited by available CPU resources and unable to process more requests. Also any other CPU intensive processes that you could eventually run on that machine will hit your NodeJS process. On the other hand Python process doesn't take all available CPU resources and probably could scale with a number of requests.

Answer (score 0):

So these times are not reliable in and of themselves, they say how long the process took to perform an action on the CPU. This is coupled very tightly to whatever else was happening at the same time on that machine and could fluctuate wildly based entirely on physical resources.

**In terms of these times specifically:**

- real = Wall Clock time (Start to finish time)
- user = Userspace CPU time (i.e. Code you wrote/might look at) e.g. node/python libs/your code
- sys = Kernel CPU time (i.e. Syscalls, e.g Open a file from the OS.)

Specifically, small real time means it actually finished faster. Does it mean it did it better for sure, NO. There could have been less happening on the machine at the same time for instance.

In terms of scale, these numbers are a little irrelevant, and it depends on the architecture/bottlenecks. For instance, in terms of scale and specifically, cloud compute, it's about efficiently allocating resources and the relevant IO for each, generally (compute, disk, network). Does processing this image as fast as possible help with scale? Maybe? You need to examine bottlenecks and specifics to be sure. It could for instance overwhelm your network link and then you are constrained there, before you hit compute limits. Or you might be constrained by how quickly you can write to the disk.

Comment: All this happening locally, pick a file from a folder, write it to another. So no network bottlenecks. The times have remained in similar ratios between node and python over several hours/days, so no uncertainty about other processes running that might be impacting this time

Answer (score 0):

One potentially important aspect of this which no one mention is the fact that your library (vips) will itself launch threads:
http://www.vips.ecs.soton.ac.uk/supported/current/doc/html/libvips/using-threads.html

> When libvips calculates an image, by default it will use as many
>   threads as you have CPU cores. Use vips_concurrency_set() to change
>   this.

This explains the thing that surprised me initially the most -- NodeJS should (to my understanding) be pretty single threaded, just as Python with its GIL.  It being all about asynchronous processing and all.
So perhaps Python and Node bindings for vips just use different threading settings.  That's worth investigating.

(that said, a quick look doesn't find any evidence of changes to the default concurrency levels in either library)